# Some strange things with img in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

Sometimes when adding an img to custom field it look strange (dots or bad quality), but if I delete this bad image and upload it again it will be okay.

I cannot understand what causes this.

Below is a screenshot. Perhaps someone has seen such a thing before?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This certainly looks strange. Any plugins processing images for you?

Comment: I think no, but I guess that this is going because of the server. If the picture is larger for instance than 200 kb, such things are happening.

Comment: I would probably start by disabling all plugins to see if the problem goes away. If not, then yes, perhaps try on a different server to see if that's the problem.